# Free SQL In Google App Engine

Tags: sql, google-app-engine

I am new to GAE and I am trying to develop an app to learn. I need to use SQL but as I searched on the GAE Site, GAE's SQL(Cloud SQL) is no more free of cost. Does any one know some means by which I can use SQL free of cost in GAE App????

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in learning about Google App Engine development with SQL, you can [use a local instance of MySQL](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/developers-guide#using_the_python_development_server) and the Python `dev_appserver` environment to experiment. While this won't be exactly the same as deployment to production, you will be able to learn a significant bit about App Engine development.